# How to create a fillable PDF file with many identical-looking but distinct boxes

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I want to make a document with dozens of identical looking boxes (as in first name, last name) that will be filled with different text.

If I copy/paste my code to generate the boxes then the resulting PDF will have the property that once a box is typed-in the other boxes will fill with the same entry.

Is there a quick/smart way of doing this task?

```
 \documentclass{paper}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{Form}[action=mailto:me@univ.edu?subject={The form},method=post]
 \TextField[width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type Last Name} 
 \vskip .1in
 \TextField[width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type First Name}
 \vskip .1in
 \TextField[width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type Last Name} 
 \vskip .1in
 \TextField[width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type First Name}
 \vskip .1in
 \end{Form}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: the fields must have distinct names. You can use a counter and a new command which increases the counter at every call.

Comment: Can  you provide an example? When I add a tag it solves the uniqueness issue but it appears next to the box. the "name" becomes visible.

Comment: you can use the key `name=XXX` in the options. And if you want an example you will have to provide one first, I won't create one from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ulrike said in the comments all you need is a counter and then use the counter in the `name` key of each text box:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{textboxid}
\newcommand{\instextboxes}{%
  \stepcounter{textboxid}%
  \TextField[name=TextBox\thetextboxid, width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type Last Name}%
  \vspace{0.1in}%
  \par
  \stepcounter{textboxid}%
  \TextField[name=TextBox\thetextboxid, width=5cm, height=0.6cm]{Type First Name}%
  \vspace{0.1in}%
  \par}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}[action=mailto:me@univ.edu?subject={The form},method=post]
  \instextboxes
  \instextboxes
  \instextboxes
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```